# Maximum independent subset for graphs with lots of edges

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, time-complexity, np-hard, polynomial-time-reductions

Consider an NP-hard graph problem, like the maximum independent set problem.

Let us say I restrict my inputs to only be graphs that have $n$ vertices and at least $n^{c}$ edges, for some $c > 1$. In other words, the graphs are very connected.

Is the maximum independent set problem still hard for these graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is still $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. For example, take a hard instance $G = (V,E)$ of the original maximum independent set problem. Add a new vertex set $V'$ to the graph such that $|V'| = |V|$ and $V'$ forms a complete graph. Also, there are no edges between $V$ and $V'$. Let the new graph be $G' = (V' \cup V, E')$ which is also a hard instance. And, $|V' \cup V| = 2n$ and $|E'| = \Theta(n^2)$.

Formally, it holds that $G$ has an independent set off size $k$ if and only if $G'$ has an independent set of size $k+1$.

---

Even if you add edges between every vertex of $V$ and every vertex of $V'$, the reduced instance would be a hard instance. Then, it holds that $G$ has an independent set of size $k$ if and only if $G'$ has an independent set of size $k$.

Comment: When you mean "For example, take a hard instance $G = (V,E)$ for the problem." in the first line, do you mean take a hard instance of the original maximum independent set problem? Also, is there any edge between the vertices in $V'$ and the vertices in $V$?

Comment: @SidMeyers I have added more details.